# Powershell Start-Process VS Invoke-Item

Tags: powershell, start-process

What's the difference between `Start-Process` and `Invoke-Item`?  I noticed that you can't `Invoke-Item chrome`.  I assume that `Invoke-Item` is specifically for files with a given file path.  But are there any advantages to using `Invoke-Item` instead of `Start-Process` (besides that typing `ii` is faster than typing `start`)?

Comment: `Invoke-Item` is (basically) the same as double-clicking on a file that has an extension registered.  It will use whatever is registered to open that file.  `Start-Process` is an abstraction for using the `Process` .NET class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Invoke-Item` cmdlet performs the default action on the specified item. For example, it runs an executable file or opens a document file in the application associated with the document file type. The default action depends on the type of item and is determined by the PowerShell provider that provides access to the data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-item?view=powershell-6

The `Start-Process` cmdlet starts one or more processes on the local computer. To specify the program that runs in the process, enter an executable file or script file, or a file that can be opened by using a program on the computer. If you specify a non-executable file, `Start-Process` starts the program that is associated with the file, similar to the `Invoke-Item` cmdlet.

You can use the parameters of `Start-Process` to specify options, such as loading a user profile, starting the process in a new window, or using alternate credentials.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-6

Comment: So `Start-Process` is an abstraction over `Invoke-Item` which calls the latter when necessary, but `Start-Process` consequently provides more control of how it invokes the provided argument?